# Comparing same string fails in Ruby with same utf-8 encoding

Tags: ruby

The string from the one side came from server scraping, so they might be different, but they look the same:

```
irb(main):013:0> "‎italy" == "italy"
=> false
```

I checked encoding and it's the same

```
irb(main):014:0> "‎italy".encoding === "italy".encoding
=> true

irb(main):016:0> "‎italy".encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

Why are they different (==) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first string contains a [LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm) at the beginning. This isn’t visible when you print the string, but it does mean the strings are different. Compare the result of calling `bytes` or `chars` on the strings.

You will need to strip it off before processing the string.

Comment: How did you find it? What ruby or js function should I use to make them equal? Consider as reference a string written in ruby console.

Comment: @sparkle I just copy and pasted the strings from your question into the console, assigning them to variables, then you can investigate. e.g. if you copy the first string into `a = "‎italy"`, then `a.chars` will show the extra character as `""` and `a.codepoints` will show the codepoint.

Comment: ok, thanks. How can I remove this extra character in ruby?

Comment: `"‎italy".encode!("ASCII", invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: '')`

Comment: Without the  "!" it works with nil too. Otherwise I get "can't modify frozen String: """ nil.to_s.encode!("ASCII", invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: '')